# Excel - Converting certain formulae to values - performance issues

Tags: excel, vba

I am working with a series of large workbooks and using a tool to import values from a financial database (SAP Financial Consolidation). The way it works is by using UDFs such as `=GetCtData({parameters})` or `=GetCtLabel({parameters})`. One of the parameters is the output value of the cell, such that at any point the value of the cell is a number.

To share these workbooks with others who do not have the Financial Consolidation add-in I need to convert each of these cells to values. I don't want to convert all cells to values, only the cells with the `=GetCt...` formulae. Below is the code I have written so far, which has three (similar) approaches (two are commented out). It works perfectly on small workbooks but the files have now grown such that there are perhaps a total of 250,000+ cells which need updating. (Roughly 70 columns x 350 rows x 10+ worksheets.) I've tried running it but after a couple of hours it is still going.

Can anyone suggest a more efficient method?

```
Sub removeAllMagnitudeLinks()

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    Application.EnableEvents = False

    For Each sSheet In Worksheets
        If sSheet.Name <> "blankMagnitude" Then 'Don't remove links from the blankMagnitude sheet -- unnecessary
            If sSheet.FilterMode Then sSheet.ShowAllData

            Application.StatusBar = "Working on sheet #" & sSheet.Index & " of " & Worksheets.Count & ". Name: " & sSheet.Name

            On Error Resume Next
            While Err.Number = 0
                With sSheet.Cells.Find(What:="GetCt", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
'                    .Copy 'Copying and pasting is one approach, but may not be fastest
'                    .PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
'                    .Formula = .Value 'This is another approach, which is certainly not very fast
                    .Value = .Value
                End With
            Wend
        End If
    Next sSheet
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a quite old post so I guess you've solved this already just like I had to do the same. The code below actually works on really huge files as well and not that 'nice' as I am not a programmer.

The other solution which I have is an add-in with UDFs in the [non-SAP BFC] excel of the users which allow users with no access to  BFC/Magnitude to open files with BFC functions [getctdata, getctlabel]. Reply to the post if you are interested in this one.

I hope on a day SAP wakes up and will provide all these as part of the application.

```
Sub killMagnitude()
Dim x As Double, y As Double, sorok As Double, Z As Double
Dim c, i As Long
Dim sor, oszlop As Long

'paste-special cells with links to magnitude data
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.EnableEvents = False


c = Application.Worksheets.Count
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

For i = 1 To c
Worksheets(i).Activate
Application.StatusBar = "removing magnitude links from sheet: " & Worksheets(i).Name
On Error Resume Next
Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Select

x = ActiveCell.Row ' a tartomány -ig sora
y = ActiveCell.Column 'a tartomány -ig oszlopa

On Error GoTo 0


For sor = 1 To x
    For oszlop = 1 To y
    If Cells(sor, oszlop).HasFormula = True Then
    Z = InStr(1, Cells(sor, oszlop).Formula, "GetCtData", 0)

        If Z <> 0 Then
            Cells(sor, oszlop).Value = Cells(sor, oszlop).Value
        Else
        End If

    Z = InStr(1, Cells(sor, oszlop).Formula, "GetCtLabel", 0)

        If Z <> 0 Then
            Cells(sor, oszlop).Value = Cells(sor, oszlop).Value
        Else
        End If

    Else
    End If
    Next oszlop
Next sor

GoTo skip

skip:

Next i
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
Application.StatusBar = "magnitude calculations removed from workbook"

Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I would try the variant array approach something like this

```
Sub removeAllMagnitudeLinks()
    Dim sSheet As Worksheet
    Dim vFormulas As Variant
    Dim vValues As Variant
    Dim j As Long
    Dim k As Long
    Dim strFormula As String
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    Application.EnableEvents = False

    For Each sSheet In Worksheets
        If sSheet.Name <> "blankMagnitude" Then    'Don't remove links from the blankMagnitude sheet -- unnecessary
            If sSheet.FilterMode Then sSheet.ShowAllData

            Application.StatusBar = "Working on sheet #" & sSheet.Index & " of " & Worksheets.Count & ". Name: " & sSheet.Name

            vFormulas = sSheet.UsedRange.Formula
            vValues = sSheet.UsedRange.Value2
            For j = LBound(vFormulas) To UBound(vFormulas)
                For k = LBound(vFormulas, 2) To UBound(vFormulas, 2)
                    strFormula = CStr(vFormulas(j, k))
                    If Len(strFormula) > 0 Then
                        If Left$(strFormula, 1) = "=" Then
                            If InStr(1, strFormula, "GetCt", vbTextCompare) Then
                                vFormulas(j, k) = vValues(j, k)
                            End If
                        End If
                    End If
                Next k
            Next j
            sSheet.UsedRange.Formula = vFormulas

        End If
    Next sSheet
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks. Just tried this (finally -- sorry!) but got an Out of Memory error on the `vFormulas = sSheet.UsedRange.Formula` line on one of my worksheets. Turns out the UsedRange property was returning `$1:$1217`, so I hardcoded the range and that solved that issue. The routine is also not coping with my UDF, and is breaking all array formulas. I will keep refining it -- watch this space!

Answer (score 0):

Excel books saved to XML format look something like

```
...
<Row>
 <Cell ss:Index="2" ss:Formula="=4+2"><Data ss:Type="Number">6</Data><NamedCell
   ss:Name="MyRange"/></Cell>
</Row>
<Row>
 <Cell ss:Index="2" ss:Formula="=5+2"><Data ss:Type="Number">7</Data><NamedCell
   ss:Name="MyRange"/></Cell>
</Row>
...
```

This should be easy to parse and mass replace with regex or such (I can provide the code if required) **if** not saving VB project with the book would not cause you too much trouble.

Answer (score 0):

This may not be a generic solution, but this is a simple approach i'd follow. 
1. Open a new file Book1, and jump back to your workbook
2. Find/Replace-All in the workbook =GetCt to =[Book1]Sheet1!$A$1 
3. BreakLinks to Book1
Explanation of BreakLinks: it disconnects all links to that file and converts cells with references to it to values. 
I avoid UDFs as much as possible as they are prone to inefficiency compared to inbuilt methods written by MS Excel developers.